# react render blank screen when redirect ( no Switch from react-router-dom )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, routes, react-router

im using templete and it use old version of react & routing
i want to redirect user to login if not
but this templet have diffrent routing method
in app.js

- "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
- "react": "^16.6.3",
- "react-dom": "^16.6.3",

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { routes } from "./routes";
import withTracker from "./withTracker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./shards-dashboard/styles/shards-dashboards.1.1.0.min.css";


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
    };
    //this.checkAuth = this.checkAuth.bind(this);
  }
 // checkAuth() {}
  componentDidMount() {
    // this.checkAuth();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASENAME || ""}>
        <div>
          {routes.map((route, index) => (
            <Route
              key={index}
              path={route.path}
              exact={route.exact}
              component={withTracker((props) => {
                return (
                  <route.layout {...props}>
                    <route.component {...props} />
                  </route.layout>
                );
              })}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

and there is routes.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// Layout Types
import { DefaultLayout } from "./layouts";
import LogLayout from "./layouts/LogLayout";
// Route Views

import TransactionsOverView from "./views/TransactionsOverview";
import TransferList from "./views/TransferList";
import Settings from "./views/Settings";
import History from "./views/History";
import AdminAccsess from "./components/logSign/AdminAccsess";
import TransactionPermission from "./views/TransactionPermission";
import Charge from "./views/Charge";
import Users from "./views/Users";

export const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: () => <Redirect to="/transactions-overview" />,
  },
  {
    path: "/transactions-overview",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: TransactionsOverView,
  },
  {
    path: "/users",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Users,
  },
  {
    path: "/settings",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Settings,
  },
  {
    path: "/charge",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Charge,
  },

  {
    path: "/history",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: History,
  },
  {
    path: "/transfer",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: TransferList,
  },
  {
    path: "/permission",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: TransactionPermission,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    layout: LogLayout,
    component: AdminAccsess,
  },
];
```

cant use context or hooks and i dont want to use redux just for this
i tried make condition in app.js
but it always show blank screen
or it redirect without changing to path
is there any idea how to solve this

cant use componentdidmount in routes.js

Comment: I would use react-router version 6

Comment: Where does your authentication state come from? What are you using to determine when to redirect to log in? Can you update to at least `react-router-dom@5`? It's a major release version but the component APIs are identical, it's only had a change in the `history` dependency IIRC. Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example that includes all relevant code and details?

Comment: i use firebase ..
if i update react router i got a lot of error...
its big templete to update and rerwrite a lot of code

Comment: thats the problem 
i cant use auth state in routes.js to make condition routing
because its not a component so cant use componentdidmount or update

Comment: What's the problem? You haven't shown us enough yet.

Comment: the problem is :
i cant use condition routing in routes.js because its not class component
and if i use it in app.js ... it render blank screen 
i think using redux just for this not worth it

Comment: That's simply just not true. Class components are irrelevant here. If you disagree then please share a code example that shows it. You don't need redux for routing. I've only asked for where your authentication state is, and for how you determine ***IF*** a redirect should occur.

Comment: i edited my code.. any idea how to make it from routes.js ! & thnxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a property to the routes you want to protect:

Example:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: () => <Redirect to="/transactions-overview" />,
  },
  {
    path: "/transactions-overview",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: TransactionsOverView,
  },
  {
    path: "/users",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Users,
    isAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/settings",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Settings,
  },
  {
    path: "/charge",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Charge,
    isAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/history",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: History,
    isAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/transfer",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: TransferList,
    isAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/permission",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: TransactionPermission,
    isAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    layout: LogLayout,
    component: AdminAccsess,
  },
];
```

Then while mapping over the routes check this `isAuth` property and conditionally render a `Redirect` to login or the routed component.

Example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
    };
    //this.checkAuth = this.checkAuth.bind(this);
  }
 // checkAuth() {}
  componentDidMount() {
    // this.checkAuth();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASENAME || ""}>
        <div>
          {routes.map((route) => {
            const { isAuth, path, exact } = route;

            if (isAuth && !this.state.isAuthenticated) {
              return <Redirect key={path} exact={exact} from={path} to="/login" />;
            }

            return (
              <Route
                key={path}
                path={path}
                exact={exact}
                component={withTracker((props) => (
                  <route.layout {...props}>
                    <route.component {...props} />
                  </route.layout>
                ))}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give isLogin data from redux and declare a condition inside a '/' route.
like this:

```
{
 path: "/",
 exact: true,
 layout: DefaultLayout,
 component: isLogin ? Home : Login,
},
```

just i think you should declare routes inside the main component for accessing to isLogin props.

Comment: yep ... but should i use  Redux for just this ? i think its oversize if i use it just for share one state